# Create Tabs and Drag/Drop Them In Application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I currently have a program in .NET 3.5, written in Visual Studio C# using Windows Forms. I plan on rewriting this program from the ground up, its a very small and simple program, so its not that big of a feat.

With the new version of the program, I would like to give users the ability to add/remove tabs from a tabControl, as well as drag and drop them to re-arrange them in the order they like. I know they can not do this with Windows Form. Would I be able to do this if I create the program using WPF instead?

I also want to be able to load an webpage in the program, which would be AJAX based:
http://www.twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=8wayrun&popout_chat=true

Would I be able to do all this with WPF, even though I cant do it in WF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project can help you: http://fabtab.codeplex.com